# problem in importing images in flutter using image.asset()

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-devtools

I'm constantly getting this error saying:

> The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec: Unable to
> load asset: ../images/mall.png

Even though the YAML file is correct.

This is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.0-10.0.dev <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

 
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0



# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
```

Comment: can you add your `pubspec.yaml` in the question

Comment: app your project structure, your pusbcpec, and assets

Answer (score 0):

Your `pubspec.yaml` should look something like this:

```
assets:
   - images/mall.png
   - images/example.png
```

and not

```
assets:
   - images/
```

Add the all images you need.

Comment: tried the same but no luck any other suggestions ??

Comment: Have you tried restarting your App after doing a `flutter clean` and a `flutter pub get`?

Comment: yeah tried that too also validated the YAML file online but no luck

Comment: Could you please add the code you are using to display the asset into the app?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named as assets in **PROJECT DIRECTORY**
not in lib or some other folder. Drag and drop your image into assets folder.
Now your pubspec.yaml would be like

assets:

- assets/

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you have a path that looks like:

> /assets/images/mall.png

but your pubspec.yaml is saying it's:

> /images/mall.png

and can't find it.

Make sure your filetree is the same as you're telling it is in pubspec.yaml and don't forget to indent correctly.

To be clear:

> assets:
>
> - images/

does NOT mean /assets/images/

it should then be:

> assets:
>
> - assets/images/